# Coverity error: unable to run native compiler sanity test for qcc

Tags: coverity, qcc

I am trying to setup coverity  in my system, while configuring the compiler I am getting the below error:

[image]

I have uninstall the setup and try to install freshly but no luck yet.
Any body has any idea?

Comment: It is preferred to post messages as text, not images. It would help readers, and people searching, if you could paste the text into your post. Anyway, it looks to me like Coverity simply does not support the compiler you're trying to use. Does anything indicate that it does support it?

Answer (score 0):

This typically occurs when the compiler does not run in the environment you're using with `cov-configure`.

A quick and easy way to check would be to attempt to compile something trivial and simple - like a "Hello World" program in the same console window that you're running `cov-configure` from. Since Coverity does support that version of QNX, I expect the issue is an environment one.